# Can't modify self in ruby for integer

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a way in ruby to chain a destructive method to change the value of a variable by one, but I'm getting errors saying `Can't change the value of self`. Is this something not possible in Ruby?

```
guesses_left = 3

class Integer
  def decrement_guess_count!
    self -= 1
  end
end

guesses_left.decrement_guess_count!
```

Comment: If this worked, 3 would hold the value 2 after decrement_guess_count! was called. You don't want to manipulate the instance of an integer. Perhaps this is a sign that guesses_left should be a more semantically appropriate class?

Comment: @bheeshmar But isn't there a way to make it so that self is referencing the chained variable, and not the actual value of an integer? Or any other remote possible way of doing this?

Comment: Modifying a `String` or an `Array` in place (with a bang method) is a lot different than modifying an `Integer` in place.

Comment: @bswinnerton No, self is a keyword. Perhaps a delegator ala SimpleDelegator? But again, I think what you need is decrement_guess_count! to be a method on a class (Game?) that modifies an instance variable `@guesses_left`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's by design. It's not specific to integers, all classes behave like that. For some classes (`String`, for example) you can change **state** of an instance (this is called destructive operation), but you can't completely replace the object. For integers you can't change even state, they don't have any.

If we were willing to allow such thing, it would raise a ton of hard questions. Say, what if `foo` references `bar1`, which we're replacing with `bar2`. Should `foo` keep pointing to `bar1`? Why? Why it should not? What if `bar2` has completely different type, how users of `bar1` should react to this? And so on.

```
class Foo
  def try_mutate_into another
    self = another
  end
end


f1 = Foo.new
f2 = Foo.new

f1.try_mutate_into f2
# ~> -:3: Can't change the value of self
# ~>         self = another
# ~>               ^
```

I challenge you to find a language where this operation is possible. :)

Comment: So is there no way to tackle what it is I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, not from within instance method of integer class.

Comment: Good answer. You may want to point out that `SimpleDelegator` might be useful to have an integer-like mutable object?